# Why is there a difference in the phase when using fft versus a manual DFT on a cosine signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, phase, cosine

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I can't find a good answer anywhere.

If I have a time-domain cosine signal of the form:

$$x(t) = A\mathrm{cos}(\omega_0 t)$$

Then this will result in an Fourier transform with spectrum:

$$X(\omega)=\frac{A}{2}\delta(\omega-\omega_0) + \frac{A}{2}\delta(\omega+\omega_0)  $$

I can generate these results in MATLAB using either fft or doing a summation of DFT. For example:

```
f = 1; %cosine frequency
A = 20; %cosine amplitude

w = 2*pi*f;
fs = 16; %sample rate in Hz
N = 2; %number of seconds
t = 0:1/fs:(fs*N)-1; %time vector

L = length(t); %length of time
df = fs/L; %frequency spacing
fAxis = (0:df:(fs-df)) - (fs-mod(L,2)*df)/2; %frequency vector


%time domain signal
x = A*cos(w*t);

%FFT of time domain signal
Xfft = fftshift(fft(x)/L);

%DFT of time domain signal
n=(-floor(L/2):1:floor(L/2))';
k=n';
Xdft = (1/L)*sum(x.*exp(-1i*2*pi*n.*k/L),2);
```

If I take the difference between the modulus of each spectrum, the difference is on the order of 10^-15. So the amplitudes are identical as expected.

However, I was surprised to find that the phases are quite different:

```
plot(fAxis,angle(Xdft)*180/pi,'--r');; hold on
plot(fAxis,angle(Xfft)*180/pi,'-k','LineWidth',2); hold on
grid on;
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Phase Angle (deg)')
legend('DFT','FFT')
set(gca,'FontSize',14)
```

Result:

[image]

The phase of the DFT jumps around between -180 and 180 degrees, which makes sense since the phase should be either -180 or 180 (it also has some zeros as well?). However, I'm confused by the fft phase angle. It looks like it is a constantly increasing function which phase wraps.

I understand that the real and imaginary parts are $\approx 0$ at all values not equal to $\omega_0$. So is this just a case of numerical imprecision at calculating the angle for small numbers? If this were the case, then at 1 Hz (i.e. where the delta spike is) I would expect the fft phase angle to match the DFT phase angle. But they don't there either. Is there something about the fft algorithm that causes the phase to be different when compared to DFT? Or am I making some error somewhere in my code/reasoning?

Comment: Be careful comparing expressions in continuous-time and continuous-frequency to their counterparts in discrete-time and discrete-frequency.  There are scaling issues both in the independent variable ($t$ and $n$ or $\omega$ and $k$) and in the dependent variable ($x(t)$ and $x[n]$ or $X(\omega)$ and $X[k]$). To make a good direct comparison, you might want to review the Riemann integral.  That's a good way to compare the integrals and dirac impulses in the continuous-time/frequency domain to the summations and kronecker impulses in the discrete-time/frequency domain.

Answer (score 4):

Check the [Matlab definition of their FFT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#buuutyt-5).

If I change the code

```
%DFT of time domain signal
n=(-floor(L/2):1:floor(L/2))';
k=n';
Xdft = (1/L)*sum(x.*exp(-1i*2*pi*n.*k/L),2);
```

to

```
%DFT of time domain signal
n = 1:L;
k=n';
Xdft = (1/L)*sum(x.*exp(-1i*2*pi*(n-1).*(k-1)/L),2);
```

and then plot the two

```
plot(fAxis,angle(Xfft)*180/pi,'-k','LineWidth',20); hold on
plot(fAxis,angle(Xdft)*180/pi,'r+');; hold on
grid on;
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Phase Angle (deg)')
legend('DFT','FFT')
set(gca,'FontSize',14)
```

Then I get the two overlapping precisely.

#### Note: I do not use `fftshift` in my plots.

[image: Both phases plotted.]

If I plot the magnitudes:

```
plot(abs(Xfft));
hold on;
plot(abs(Xdft),'r+')
```

Then I get the following plot.

[image: Magnutude responses.]

---

#### Why?

So let's look at the differences between the OP code and my code.

The first difference is between:

```
Xfft = fftshift(fft(x)/L);
```

and

```
Xfft = fft(x)/L;
```

This means that my labels (which I didn't change) are incorrect. So instead of the frequency range being:

```
fAxis = (0:df:(fs-df)) - (fs-mod(L,2)*df)/2; %frequency vector
```

it's really

```
fAxis = (0:df:(fs-df)); %frequency vector
```

And this leads to an error in my plots (which I am not currently going to correct, so you can see the error).

The other difference is in the direct calculation of the DFT

```
n=(-floor(L/2):1:floor(L/2))';
k=n';
Xdft = (1/L)*sum(x.*exp(-1i*2*pi*n.*k/L),2);
```

which is

\begin{align*}
X_{\tt dft}[k] &= \frac{1}{L} \sum_{n=-\lfloor L/2 \rfloor}^{\lfloor L/2 \rfloor} x[n + \lfloor L/2 \rfloor] e^{-\jmath 2\pi n k /L}\\
&= \frac{1}{L} \sum_{n'=0}^{L-1} x[n'] e^{-\jmath 2\pi (n' - \lfloor L/2 \rfloor) k /L}\\
&= e^{\jmath 2\pi \lfloor L/2 \rfloor k/L} \frac{1}{L} \sum_{n'=0}^{L-1} x[n'] e^{-\jmath 2\pi n'k /L}\\
&= e^{\jmath \pi k} \frac{1}{L} \sum_{n'=0}^{L-1} x[n'] e^{-\jmath 2\pi n'k /L}
\end{align*}

(assuming $L$ is even) versus

```
n = 1:L;
k=n';
Xdft = (1/L)*sum(x.*exp(-1i*2*pi*(n-1).*(k-1)/L),2);
```

which is

$$
X_{\tt dft}[k] = \frac{1}{L} \sum_{n=0}^{L-1} x[n] e^{-\jmath 2\pi n k /L}
$$

where, in both cases, I'm assuming $x[n]$ is non-zero for $0\le n \le L-1$.

#### Reproducing with FFT

`k = n'` means the *input* is also fftshifted. Changing

```matlab
Xfft = fftshift(fft(x)/L);
```

to

```matlab
Xfft = fftshift(fft(ifftshift(x))/L);
```

yields

[image]

The few mismatches are likely explained by float limitations. Interestingly, something else happens if we do `fftshift(x)` instead, but that's for another day.

Comment: I get confused by your use of the semicolon. `;`.  Especially the double `;;`.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson That was in the original code. I didn't notice! Matlab just ignores it, in effect.

Comment: But if I make the change as you suggested, then amplitudes won't align. Is this just a matter of shifting the x axis around? It causes no end in confusion the way that MATLAB requires the fftshift(fft(x))...

Comment: @Darcy Go back to basics: go to the matlab site I linked to and see how they've defined it.  Matlab doesn't *require* anything of the sort (`fftshift`). You may want to use if for display of centered data. I rarely do. I just plot the positive frequencies if it's an issue.

Comment: I'm still having trouble seeing why that small change in the indexing changes the phase. And there seems to be an inconsistency since if I make your change then the amplitudes don't align (along a common x axis binning).

Comment: @Darcy The amplitudes align perfectly. See my update with code and plot.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to mention `fftshift(fft(x))` -> `fft(x)`. Your edit makes it a standard FFT.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Correct! That's why I showed the plot commands I used, but it should be called out. Added a note to that effect.

Comment: I get that this is a workaround and OP may not care, but the question does ask _why_ there's the observed difference if coding as OP does, which I think is a valid and interesting question.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Agreed. Made the start of an attempt to explain. Let me know what I've done wrong.

Comment: That's explaining why there "may be any difference at all", not why "there's this particular difference". One is piecewise-linear, other a scrambled mess, and it's unclear why an array shift does this. It's not a pure shift per changed float roundoff via changed order of operations, so the answer must lie both in the specific phase values and the unwrapping step.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Doesn't the fact that there's a $e^{-\jmath \pi k}$ multiplier mostly explain it? That's a sequence of +1 and -1, repeated that makes the *scrambled mess*.

Comment: Ah, OP is also changing ***n***. Yes that can totally explain it - both should be stated explicitly in the answer, the e^ and `n`. So OP is _not_ doing just an `fftshift`. Though that this is happening upon a sine is a bit bizarre to me, I'll try to look later - the way to test is to fftshift both the input and the output and see if it also happens with `fft`, so `fftshift(fft(fftshift(x)))` (but it may be `ifftshift` on input, unsure). The plots also aren't perfectly uniform in +1, -1, +1, -1, but maybe that part's float precision or plot artifact.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Thanks for the update! :-)